# How to use vuetify.css and bootstrap in one page?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuetify.js

I want to use both the `vuetify.min.css` folder and `bootstratp.min.css` folder. Bootstrap is defined on the layout page and I need vuetify.min.css on another page. Is there any way to use both of them together?

Comment: I'm sure you could but it would make your app pretty heavy. Why do you need them both? What does one do that the other doesn't?

Comment: I need some button css's. However, vuetify css file crashes bootstrap.  When I use both of them posts are growing.

Comment: If it is just some buttons could you not just write your own css for them?

Comment: Because these are already exist in vuetify

Comment: Why can't you copy the button CSS from Vuetify if that's all you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions here:

1. Prefix one of the libraries like so:
   https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9454
2. Only get what you need from the BS4 library (using SCSS) like so:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/buttons.scss";
```

3. Switch to BS3 for your button styling and create a [custom package](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/).

In my opinion the best solution is the second, get it working in your setup and build the files you need. More info on Theming BS4 [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/).