# Vuetify & Webpack - Error compiling custom variables (sass-loader failed)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm experience an issue with compiling Vuetify variables. Per the original documentation and some Stack Overflow answers, I've made some changes to the files, but I'm still getting compiling errors.

Logs

```
ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: $color: ("base": #2196F3, "lighten-5": #E3F2FD, "lighten-4": #BBDEFB, "lighten-3": #90CAF9, "lighten-2": #64B5F6, "lighten-1": #42A5F5, "
darken-1": #1E88E5, "darken-2": #1976D2, "darken-3": #1565C0, "darken-4": #0D47A1, "accent-1": #82B1FF, "accent-2": #448AFF, "accent-3": #2979FF, "a
ccent-4": #2962FF) is not a color.
    ╷
178 │ $link-hover-color:                        darken($link-color, 15%) !default;
    │                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_variables.scss 178:43  @import
  node_modules\bootstrap\scss\bootstrap.scss 9:9      @import
  resources\sass\app.scss 8:9                         root stylesheet
    at processResult (C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:598:19)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:692:5
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:62:7
    at Function.call$2 (C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:91729:16)
    at _render_closure1.call$2 (C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:80373:12)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:27269:18)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25797:19)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:26094:49)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:4543:77)
    at _Future._completeError$2 (C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25927:9)
    at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError$2 (C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25270:12)
    at Object._asyncRethrow (C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:4292:17)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\thumin\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:13233:20

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
```

app.scss

```css
// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

variables.scss

```css
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/main.sass';
$body-font-family: 'Cairo', serif;
```

vue.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                sassOptions: {
                    prependData: `@import "@/assets/css/variables.scss";`,
                }
            }
        }
    },
    transpileDependencies: [
        'vuetify',
        'vuex-persist'
    ]
}
```

package.json

```json
"sass": "^1.32.0",
"sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
```

Error;

```
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: $color: ("base": #2196F3, "lighten-5": #E3F2FD, "lighten-4": #BBDEFB, "lighten-3": #90CAF9, "lighten-2": #64B5F6, "lighten-1": #42A5F5, "darken-1": #1E88E5,
 "darken-2": #1976D2, "darken-3": #1565C0, "darken-4": #0D47A1, "accent-1": #82B1FF, "accent-2": #448AFF, "accent-3": #2979FF, "accent-4": #2962FF) is not a color.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55429699/8810271 might help

Comment: my goal of this is to just override default vuetify theme options, like font-family, etc.

Comment: What's the content of `main.sass`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Fix Vue config

1. `prependData` was renamed to [`additionalData`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#additionaldata) in [`sass-loader` v9](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v9.0.0). Since you're using `sass-loader` v10, switch to `additionalData`.
2. [`additionalData`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#additionaldata) is actually a sibling of `sassOptions` (not a child property). `sassOptions` is intended for the underlying Sass implementation (*Dart Sass* or *Node Sass*).
3. In my experiments, `additionalData` for both `sass` and `scss` was needed to bring in the global `variables.scss`.

*Example:*

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `@import "~@/assets/css/variables.scss"`
      },
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "~@/assets/css/variables.scss";`
      },
    }
  },
}
```

#### Fix Bootstrap error

I was able to reproduce the error only when adding `src/styles/variables.scss` to the project root, while also including `bootstrap/scss/bootstrap`. The `variables.scss` parent directory could also be `src/scss` or `src/sass` for the symptom to occur. It seems `sass-loader` resolves this file when [Bootstrap tries to import its own `variables` file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/548be2e/scss/bootstrap.scss#L11), which leads to the error.

Since you're already trying to configure a global `variables.scss` file in Vue config (pointing to `@/assets/css/variables.scss`), I assume it's ok to remove the problematic `src/styles/variables.scss` that is causing the Bootstrap error.

#### Fix `variables.scss`

`variables.scss` imports Vuetify's `main.sass`, but that isn't needed to override Vuetify variables. Also note that the `additionalData` config above would cause this file to be prepended to *all* scss/sass files, so bringing in Vuetify's `main.sass` (relatively large) would slow down the build and duplicate styles. The fix here is to remove that import.

```css
// @import '~vuetify/src/styles/main.sass'; ❌ unnecessary
$body-font-family: 'Cairo', serif;
```

*[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vuetify-override-variables) with the above fixes*

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this can help, but give it a try
Try to add `additionalData` to `sass` object not inside `sassOptions` as said in [vue-cli-docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders)

```
css: {
  loaderOptions: {
    // pass options to sass-loader
    // @/ is an alias to src/
    // so this assumes you have a file named `src/variables.sass`
    // Note: this option is named as "prependData" in sass-loader v8
    sass: {
      additionalData: `@import "~@/variables.sass"`
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In vue-cli docs you can see how to pass options to pre-processors. [Read vue-cli docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders)

So your `vue.config.js` should look like this:

```json
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      // Note: this option is named as "prependData" in sass-loader v8
      sass: {
        additionalData: `@import "~@/assets/css/variables.scss"`
      },
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "~@/assets/css/variables.scss";`
      },
    }
  },
  transpileDependencies: [
   'vuetify',
   'vuex-persist'
  ]
}
```